# get results only if match is found in RIGHT table

Tags: mysql

I have just recently started working on a dB with many-many relationships.

I have 2 tables that are basically set-up as follows:

albums - has a column called 'album_id'.

albartptr - matches albums to artists. This has 2 columns; albartptr_album_fk and albartptr_artist_fk.

Here is the query I'm working with:

```
SELECT
  album.album_id,
  album.album_title
FROM wp_musicmgr_albums album
  RIGHT JOIN wp_musicmgr_albartptr albartptr 
    ON albartptr.albartptr_artist_fk = 1
GROUP BY album.album_id
ORDER BY album_id ASC LIMIT 0,18
```

This search is returning ALL the albums regardless of what is in albartptr.

In my 'battleship' approach to trying to find the right thing, I have tried every type of join.

How can I get a list of albums ONLY if albartptr.albartptr_artist_fk = 1?

Comment: what field is the same in each field?

Comment: SOrry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Okie. Nevermind that last message. After I posted it, I looked again and realized you were on to something. I left out a matching condition for albartptr_album_fk. So, now it gets the correct items, but it also includes one null entry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to your code:

```
WHERE (SAME FIELD IN FIRST TABLE) = (SAME FIELD IN SECOND TABLE)
    AND (SAME FIELD IN WATNED RESULTS TABLE) = 1
```

This way you get what is the same in each table where it equals 1.